# Find all documents in one collection, change data and save into another collection using mongoose and node express

Tags: node.js, angular, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm trying get select data from 1 collection, remove the fields I don't need, and add some new fields, and passing the data needed which is being replicated on each document for the new fields, and save them into a different collection.

Am I getting close or am I way off?  Any help would be appreciated.

```
router.post('', (req, res, next) => {
    const taskDay = req.body.taskDay;
    switch (taskDay) {
        case 'taskSunday':
            MasterTask.find({taskSunday: true}).forEach(tempData => {
                const taskSheet = new Tasksheet({
                    taskDate: req.body.taskDate,
                    taskTicket: req.body.taskTicket,
                    taskTime: tempData.taskTime,
                    taskCompany: tempData.taskCompany,
                    taskDescription: tempData.taskDescription,
                    taskCompleted: req.body.taskCompleted,
                    taskComments: req.body.taskComments,
                    taskCompletedBy: req.body.taskCompletedBy,
                    taskTimeStamp: req.body.taskTimeStamp,
                    taskKnowledgeTitle: tempData.taskKnowledgeTitle,
                    taskKnowledgeUrl: tempData.taskKnowledgeUrl,
                    taskType: tempData.taskType
                }); 
                Tasksheet.insertMany(taskSheet).then(result => {
                    console.log(result);
                    res.status(200).json({message: 'task sheet created'})
                });
            });
            break;
```

**Sample Data being pulled in find:**

```
    _id: "5f0acb7209e5981d10bb765a",
    taskTime: "00:00",
    taskCompany: "CompanyName",
    taskDescription: "Some Needed Daily Task",
    taskSunday: true,
    taskMonday: true,
    taskTuesday: true,
    taskWednesday: true,
    taskThursday: true,
    taskFriday: true,
    taskSaturday: true,
    taskDisable: false,
    taskEndOfMonth: null,
    taskKnowledgeTitle: "Some Title",
    taskKnowledgeUrl: "Some URL",
    taskForSpecificDays: null,
    taskType: "Core",
    __v: 0
  }
```

**Data transformation that I'm trying to save to new collection:**

```
  {
    id: "mongooseID",
    taskTicket: "",
    taskDate: null,
    taskTime: "00:00",
    taskCompany: "somename",
    taskDescription: "This is an example description of a task.  This is going to be an extra long line of text to test.",
    taskCompleted: false,
    taskComments: "",
    taskCompletedBy: "",
    taskTimeStamp: "",
    taskKnowledgeTitle: "Test",
    taskKnowledgeUrl: "http://www.google.com",
    taskType: "Core"
  }
```

Comment: You are inserting one by one. Use insertOne instead of insertMany. Also would recommend you to use save since you are already using the constructor "Tasksheet"

Comment: The find I'm doing is finding all documents in 1 collection based on critea.  So it would be a mass save.

Comment: Yes the find is returning multiple but you are running a forEach on that. right?

Comment: The foreach errors out.  I can get the find data and it's correct, but when I try to add it to the save or insert statement it doesn't give anything back.  I get a blank record with just an ID from mongoose.

Comment: I added some sample data and the transformations that I am trying to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this.

```
MasterTask.find(
{
    taskSunday: true
},
function(err, tempData) {
    let taskSheet = [];
    tempData.forEach(t => {
        taskSheet.push({
            taskDate: req.body.taskDate,
            taskTicket: req.body.taskTicket,
            taskTime: t.taskTime,
            taskCompany: t.taskCompany,
            taskDescription: t.taskDescription,
            taskCompleted: req.body.taskCompleted,
            taskComments: req.body.taskComments,
            taskCompletedBy: req.body.taskCompletedBy,
            taskTimeStamp: req.body.taskTimeStamp,
            taskKnowledgeTitle: t.taskKnowledgeTitle,
            taskKnowledgeUrl: t.taskKnowledgeUrl,
            taskType: t.taskType
        })
    })

    Tasksheet.insertMany(taskSheet, (err, t) => {
        console.log(err)
        console.log(t)
    })
})
```

Comment: And if his collection is real huge, with more then 1M documents, and his `taskSunday` field doesn't have an index, this code will never works, or will remand a huge RAM capacity.

Comment: Thank you so much, that worked perfectly!  No the Master Task will never have over 200 entries in the collection.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you do it a bit wrong. If you want to simply re-export your collection values (without modifying it) you'd better use such utilities like [`mongodump`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongodump/) or [`mongoexport`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongoexport/) (depends on scenario) and then import it via [`mongorestore`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongorestore/) or [`mongoimport`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongoimport/)

If you want to handle your problem with JS code, it's fine, but code above is a bit wrong, why is that? Because if you deal with real huge number of documents in a collection, this code will never be finished.

So it's better to use find query with a cursor, like this:

```
async function t () {
   try {
        await collection_name.find({taskSunday: true}).lean().cursor({batchSize: 10}).eachAsync(async (document) => {
                /**
                * Your could write any logic here related with your document
                */
                const taskSheet = new Tasksheet({
                    taskDate: document.taskDate,
                    taskTicket: document.taskTicket,
                    taskTime: document.taskTime,
                    taskCompany: document.taskCompany,
                    taskDescription: document.taskDescription,
                    taskCompleted: document.taskCompleted,
                    taskComments: document.taskComments,
                    taskCompletedBy: document.taskCompletedBy,
                    taskTimeStamp: document.taskTimeStamp,
                    taskKnowledgeTitle: document.taskKnowledgeTitle,
                    taskKnowledgeUrl: document.taskKnowledgeUrl,
                    taskType: document.taskType
                }); 
                taskSheet.save()
        }, { parallel: 10})
   } catch (e) {
       console.error(e)
   }
}
```

This code will be guaranteed finished, because it takes every 10 documents (it depends on `{batchSize: 10}` and `{ parallel: 10}` values) from your original `collection_name` and insert in one-by-one in 10 streams. Will allows you not load all the collection in your RAM.

And also allows you to modify the necessary data *on-the-fly*

Comment: small app and not doing anything really complex, just migrating an access app to web based.

Comment: Well, I understood that already. The code in another answer is fine, until you handles a real production database.